# XHR CORS request with upload progress and redirect fails

Tags: javascript, cors

When the response of a CORS request is a redirect, the request fails *only* when an upload event listener is set.

Comment: You asked this 3min ago, and answered it 3min ago, that's funny !!!

Comment: It's ok to ask and answer your own questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-cross-origin-request-0), requests should transparently follow redirects. However, redirects are not followed if the request is a [CORS request with preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0). So far, so good.

Now, if an XHR upload event listener is added to a CORS POST request, a CORS request with preflight is forced -- as discussed here: [CORS request is preflighted, but it seems like it should not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057303/cors-request-is-preflighted-but-it-seems-like-it-should-not-be)

The behavior is pretty obscure. It's not mentioned at all in the CORS spec, and it's a tiny note in the [XHR spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) (search for *preflight*). Especially since CORS is a red herring, the real issue is the XHR event listener.

This happens regardless of the redirect status code, unlike this post suggests: [Chrome cancels CORS XHR upon HTTP 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539403/chrome-cancels-cors-xhr-upon-http-302-redirect).

Hopefully this will save someone time debugging why their XHR CORS POST requests aren't working when they have an upload event listener.