# 405 Err on OPTIONS preflight for upload_url on Google Appengine SDK on different port #

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, cors, xmlhttprequest, blobstore

I have a Google AppEngine project that works fine in production but not locally.

There is a React browser application running locally on port 3001 and a python api service running on 9090.

When I attempt to upload files via the React client, I first call an REST endpoint that returns the blobstore `get_upload_url()` to the client. This url is something like: `http://localhost:9090/_ah/upload/aghkZXZ-...` <-- note the port is that of the python service

When I fashion a POST request to that url from the browser client to actually upload the file, I get a 405 on the OPTIONS preflight check. So far as I understand, this is due to the ports being different. This only occurs in the local App Engine SDK since I am using dispatch.yaml settings in production to have everything on the same domain/port.

I had dug into the SDK code a while ago and put a hack in place. (https://gist.github.com/blainegarrett/4d3b3081d09b4ff7be00765eb32b0d94)

However, since upgrading Google Cloud to 218.0.0, the hack was overwritten and I'm back to square one.

Here are the headers to the blobstore upload url:

```
OPTIONS /_ah/upload/aghkZXZ-Tm9uZXIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICA77ALDA HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

I am currently using vanilla XMLHttpRequest() for the upload call specifically.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to either get around the preflight check when the ports are different and/or to allow OPTIONS checks on the upload url in a less hacky way?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I'd still like to hear an answer regarding the 405 on the SDK, but I was able to dodge the preflight check by getting rid of the xhr progress listener. My original assertion that the port difference was triggering the preflight check was incorrect. It was the progress callback.

`xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) { .. }`

See research on: [CORS request is preflighted, but it seems like it should not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057303/cors-request-is-preflighted-but-it-seems-like-it-should-not-be)